# Error code C2084

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble writing a program where I have to create a text file, have the user enter some info, and then do it again two other times. Could someone help me with this? I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and I'm having a very hard time understanding. I keep getting "error C2084: 'void inOut{std::ofstream &}' already has a body.
Thanks, here is my current code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
void inOut(ofstream& streetnumber);     
void inOut(ofstream& streetname);
void inOut(ofstream& streetAddress);// function prototype

int main()
{
  string fileName;
  ofstream outFile;
  cout << "Input file name: ";
  //read the file name
  getline(cin, fileName);


  outFile.open(fileName);

  if (outFile.fail())   // check for a successful open
  {
      cout << "\nThe output file " << fileName << " was not successfully opened" << endl;
    exit(1);
  }

  inOut(outFile);  // call the function

  //close the file
  outFile.close();
  getline(cin, fileName);


  outFile.open(fileName);

  if (outFile.fail())   // check for a successful open
  {
      cout << "\nThe output file " << fileName << " was not successfully opened" << endl;
      exit(1);
  }

  inOut(outFile);  // call the function

  //close the file
  outFile.close();
  getline(cin, fileName);


  outFile.open(fileName);

  if (outFile.fail())   // check for a successful open
  {
      cout << "\nThe output file " << fileName << " was not successfully opened" << endl;
      exit(1);
  }

  inOut(outFile);  // call the function

  //close the file
  outFile.close();

  return 0;
}
void inOut(ofstream& streetnumber)
{ // number of lines of text
    string line;

    cout << "Please enter five lines of text:" << endl;

        getline(cin, line);
        streetnumber << line << endl;

    cout << "\nThe file has been successfully written." << endl;

}
void inOut(ofstream& streetname)
{
    string line;

    cout << "Please enter five lines of text:" << endl;

    getline(cin, line);
    streetname << line << endl;

    cout << "\nThe file has been successfully written." << endl;
}
void inOut(ofstream& streetAddress)
{ // number of lines of text
    string line;

    cout << "Please enter five lines of text:" << endl;

    getline(cin, line);
    streetAddress << line << endl;

    cout << "\nThe file has been successfully written." << endl;
}
```

Comment: you have three methods with same name which is not acceptable here.

Comment: C++ does not support function overloading on the basis of argument **name**, only type.

Answer (score 1):

For the compiler, the lines

```
void inOut(ofstream& streetnumber);     
void inOut(ofstream& streetname);
void inOut(ofstream& streetAddress);
```

declare just one function since the names of the functions and the argument types are the same. Since functions can be declared without the names of the arguments, they are equivalent to

```
void inOut(ofstream& );     
void inOut(ofstream& );
void inOut(ofstream& );
```

To declare three functions, you will need to use different names or change the argument types or use different number of arguments.

The simplest change would be to change the names:

```
void inOutStreetNumber(ofstream& streetnumber);     
void inOutStreetName(ofstream& streetname);
void inOutStreetAddress(ofstream& streetAddress);
```

Change the implementations and calls accordingly.

Comment: That fixes the error issue, thank you, but I still don't quite understand how to have the program ask the user to input all the information that it's supposed to.